# Google Maps jump to

Tags: ajax, maps

Complete novice question but I cannot work out how to do this:

http://www.warrensbakery.co.uk/plymouth.htm

I want to create a map with links that jump to the correct pin on the google map and shows the address.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you should elaborate your question

Comment: sorry, added a bit more info. hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom Google Maps map with several locations, each you could click on the pin itself on the map and a infowindow would open. I also wanted what I believe you're talking about - the ability to click a link outside of the map and have a particular pin's infowindow open on the map. It's actually quite easy - just set the click event to the same open infowindow event the pin has.

Relevant JavaScript

```
/* Used variables
  map = the map itself
  marker = the current pin
  infowindow = the infowindow shown on the map
    - my setup has only one infowindow and clicks just swap its content
  label = the current infowindow content
*/


// Inside loop setting each pin to the map

// Click mevent for pins
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close;
    infowindow.setContent(label);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

// Click event for link outside the map
$(relevantLink).click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$("#yourMap").offset().top}, 500);
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(label);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Douglas, I still don't fully understand, could you possibly do me a demo with a few pins? thanks so much

Comment: The exact way to do it depends on how you're using the Google Maps API to set up your map in the first place. Likely, you somewhere have an array of some sort listing all of your pin locations & information. As your code loops through the array (it's here setting up the pins on your map (one pin per array item)) simply add the second listed click event to the link that's outside of the map that you want to open the current array item on the map. Now each array item (map pin) has a click even on the pin itself and on the link outside of the map.